# How to merge multiple tables into a single table mysql

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

What I'm trying to do is a tool inventory table, I currently have a table for each tool type (Drill_bits, plyers, end_mills, ..etc ), and a person's table. I want to make a middle table that records all transactions i.e(when a tool is borrowed to a person). I assume that would look like this:

```
+--------------------+    
|transaction         |
+--------------------+
|person_id        FK |   
|tools_id         Fk |
+--------------------+
```

I don't know how to accomplish unifying all  different tool's tables into one single tools table. Is this even a good idea? Any suggestions would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: This is a [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) question and unless you have a particular *normal form* in mind, it's really not possible to answer. What you're describing here is a simple many-to-many "join table", nothing special, but it's presumably just part of the solution.